# How do I triple the output voltage of a 555 timer boost circuit?

Tags: high-voltage, boost, 555, voltage-multiplier

I currently have an output of 160V, but my application requires a minimum of 400V-500V. Is there a method to triple the existing 160V to achieve the desired voltage range of 400V-500V?

[image: This is a common boost circuit consisting of a 555 timer and other common components.]

Comment: It entirely depends on the loading circuit.

Comment: Is this for a Geiger-Mueller tube?

Comment: I forgot I made this post sorry for no responses, indeed it is for a Geiger Muller tube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your boost gives 160V after some serious output loading.
Change the topology to flyback below. Just change the inductor to transformer (iron powder core). Add R2C2D3 snubber to "catch" the voltage spikes on primary winding to not harm the mosfet.

The transformer ratio formula is **L1/L2 = (N1/N2)^2**.
(the transformer ratio N1/N2 do not have to be so low like 9/400 , because flyback topology provides some "native" boost advantage).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLbXex.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Suggestion: Either draw secondary negative side shorted to primary ground, or mention that one would need something like an opto of voltage feedback will be required in future